# Как сделать include для файлов со списками хостов в ansible?

Tags: linux, администрирование, ansible

Есть пачка файлов, которая используется с параметром `--inventory-file=`. В каждом файле - список хостов. Как сделать общий файл, который будет ссылаться на эти файлы? Т.е.

Файл `1403`:

```
[1403]
1403-01.mydomain
1403-02.mydomain
1403-03.mydomain
```

Файл `1405`:

```
[1405]
1405-01.mydomain
1405-02.mydomain
1405-03.mydomain
```

Нужно, чтобы было как-то так:

Файл `14xx`:

```
[14xx]
include = ./1403
include = ./1405
```

Искал [тут](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#inventory) и [тут](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_vars_module.html) и по [всей](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/) документации в целом, но как-то не нашёл.

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.3.2.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible не умеет делать `include` для inventory.

У вас есть два варианта:

1. Сложить все файлы в общую папку и включать её как inventory:

   ```
   ./inventory/
   ./inventory/1403
   ./inventory/1405
   ```

   Запуск `ansible-playbook -i inventory`, тогда Ansible загрузит все файлы из папки, но разумеется не будет общей группы `[14xx]`.
2. Сделать [dynamic-inventory скрипт](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html), который будет склеивать все файлы и добавлять еще одну группу.

Из комментариев:

Для удобства можно назвать папку с файлами `14xx` и положить (или сделать симлинки) отдельные файлы в нее.
Можно подключать её `-i inventory/14xx` и обращаться к группе `all`, чтобы выполнить таски на всех хостах из загруженных файлов.

Comment: Хм, но я же могу создать папку `14xx`, сложить в неё все файлы (или симлинки) кабинетов, при запуске ансибла указать папку, а не файл и в качестве группы хостов сказать `all`?

Comment: Да, так можно.  `all` будет всегда работать. Но именно группы с названием `14xx` работой через папку не добиться.

Comment: Ок, тогда дополни ответ, я его помечу.